# Why fit new TargetEncoder for test data?

Tags: categorical-encoding, h2o

In the [H2O tutorial on target encoding](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/target-encoding.html#transform-target-encoding) they recommend fitting a new TargetEncoder to the entire training set to encode the test data. Why not just use the averaged TargetEncoder fit to the training data in the k-fold cross validation?

I understand their point about overfitting not being a risk, but it seems to me like they are introducing a change in the distribution of the encoded variable between the training and test sets.

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/target-encoding.html#transform-target-encoding

Answer (score 1):

The point the documentation is trying (perhaps not clearly) to make is that cross-validation can/should be used to evaluate target-encoding a high-cardinal variable. If the target-encoded variable model shows a small CV error, you should then use target-encoding. We can then use all of the data when target-encoding a high cardinal variable. The main point: **models created during cross validation are used to assess your model-building decisions, e.g. target encoding; they are NOT the final models you use in practice- You use your entire training set.**

We cannot assess the final target-encoding variable with the training error. We will need another test set to get a better idea of the generalization error.